# Adding material to object programmatically raises MissingComponentException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to Unity, I'm sure it's a stupid question, I'm trying to add a Material to a GameObject, here's my code:

```
// this works
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
Renderer rend = cube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend.material = this.material;

// this does not work
GameObject obj1 = Resources.Load($"{basePath}/{this.componentName}") as GameObject;
Renderer rend2 = obj1.GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend2.material = this.material;
Instantiate(obj1, position, Quaternion.identity);

// this does not work too
GameObject obj2 = Resources.Load($"{basePath}/{this.componentName}") as GameObject;
GameObject instatiatedObj = Instantiate(obj2, position, Quaternion.identity);
Renderer rend3 = instatiatedObj.GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend3.material = this.material;
```

As I wrote in comment adding the material to a cube works, when I'm trying to add it to a loaded game object does not work, in both cases objects are displayed correctly but without material. In Unity the following error is displayed:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the "xxx" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Renderer to the game object "xxx". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you show us the GameObject that you are trying to instantiate from the resources folder?

Comment: It's a 3d model of type `.obj`

Comment: The error message looks quite self-explanatory to me ... Seems that the object you are loading is maybe only an empty `GameObject` root node with nothing but the default `Transform` component attached?

Comment: It could be self-explanatory, I started 2 days ago in Unity and I didn't find a solution googling... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are instantiating an `.obj` you are not instantiating a single GameObject. When looking at the hierachy you will see the name of the `.obj` and a `default` object.
See:
[image]
In that case the default object will contain the objects `MeshRenderer` component.
You have to change your code to use `GetComponentInChildren` ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html)).

```
GameObject obj1 = Resources.Load($"{basePath}/{this.componentName}") as GameObject;
Renderer rend2 = obj1.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
rend2.material = this.material;
Instantiate(obj1, position, Quaternion.identity);
```